# JavaScript array with null items when passing values ​to the ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a function in ajax that assembles a list and sends it via post to a controller.

The list is received with the items, however, these items are always empty. I made a printscreen to show my situation. How to solve?

> Java script list filled with elements

[image: Java script list filled with elements]

[image: When received at the controller, the list has the items but they are null]

> When received at the controller, the list has the items but they are null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code of controller? 
 It might need correct model to receive.

Comment: [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult AddProduct(string qtde, string[] listIngre, string[] listIngreUnicos, string[] listIngreRel, string[] listIngreGrad, string obs)

Comment: Its looks like you declare wrong parameter.

Your listIngreGrad should be declare as class and contains IdProdutoIngrediente, Qtde, etc.